# footer intersect with other divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I went that the div of footer will be dynamique when i choose to enlarge the other divs they intersect my footer 
here all my code plz colle it on your navigateur and test it to show yhe result 
there is on dropbox : https://www.dropbox.com/s/sxcd6unqilnemme/form.html?dl=0 
I want it to sit below the second row of content, but I can't seem to get it to do that, while still sitting at the bottom of the content when there is less content.

html:

```
<body onload="myfun()">
  <div id="js-manage-listing-nav" class="manage-listing-nav2">
    <div class="nav-sections">
        <ul class="list-unstyled row-space-5">
            <li class="nav-item nav-basics pre-listed nav-active" style="width:222px;margin-left:2px;" id="nav-item1">
                <a>
                    <div class="row nav-item" style="width:222px;">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 va-container">
                        <div class="text-wrap va-middle">
                            <a href="javascript:show('link1')" id="link1" > <span id="titre1" class="nav-item-name" style="margin-left:46px;"> + Informations de base </span></a>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item nav-basics pre-listed nav-active" style="width:222px;margin-left:2px;"id="nav-item2">
                    <div class="row nav-item"  style="width:222px;">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 va-container" style="width:256px">
                        <div class="text-wrap va-middle">
                         <a href="javascript:show('link2')" id="link2" ><span id="titre2" class="nav-item-name" style="margin-left:46px;"> + Adresse </span> </a>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item nav-basics pre-listed nav-active" style="width:222px;margin-left:2px;"id="nav-item3">
                <a>
                    <div class="row nav-item" style="width:222px;">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 va-container">
                        <div class="text-wrap va-middle">
                            <a href="javascript:show('link3')" id="link3" > <span id="titre3" class="nav-item-name" style="margin-left:46px;"> + Contact </span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item nav-basics pre-listed nav-active" style="width:222px;margin-left:2px;"id="nav-item4">
                <a>
                    <div class="row nav-item" style="width:222px;">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 va-container">
                        <div class="text-wrap va-middle">
                            <a href="javascript:show('link4')" id="link4" ><span id="titre4" class="nav-item-name" style="margin-left:46px;"> + Photos </span> </a>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item nav-basics pre-listed nav-active" style="width:222px;margin-left:2px;"id="nav-item5">
                <a>
                    <div class="row nav-item" style="width:222px;">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 va-container">
                        <div class="text-wrap va-middle">
                            <a href="javascript:show('link5')" id="link5" ><span id="titre5" class="nav-item-name" style="margin-left:46px;"> + Plus d'info </span> </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!--li class="nav-item nav-basics pre-listed nav-active" style="width:222px;margin-left:2px;">
                <a>
                    <div class="row nav-item" style="width:222px;">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 va-container">
                        <div class="text-wrap va-middle">
                            <a href="javascript:show('link5')" id="link5" ><span class="nav-item-name" style="margin-left:46px;"> + Plus d'info </span> </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item nav-basics pre-listed nav-active" style="width:222px;margin-left:2px;">
                <a>
                    <div class="row nav-item" style="width:222px;">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 va-container">
                        <div class="text-wrap va-middle">
                            <a href="javascript:show('link5')" id="link5" ><span class="nav-item-name" style="margin-left:46px;"> + Plus d'info </span> </a>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item nav-basics pre-listed nav-active" style="width:222px;margin-left:2px;">
                <a>
                    <div class="row nav-item">
                        <span class="nav-item-name" style="margin-left:66px;">
                         +Tarif
                         </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item nav-basics pre-listed nav-active" style="width:222px;margin-left:2px;">
                <a>
                    <div class="row nav-item">
                        <span class="nav-item-name" style="margin-left:66px;">
                          + Calendrier 
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li-->
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

<div id="gen">

     <!--div id="ent"> FORMULAIRE CLIENTS DEMANDE DE SERVICE </div><br>
     <div class="com">Catégorie 1 : Famille </div><br>
      <div id="grd">  Garde d’enfants </div> <br-->
       <div id="ent2"> </div>
         <form method="POST"  onSubmit="return Validation()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <div class="div" id="content1">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td> Nom : </td> <td>  <input name="Nom" type="text" class="input-textarea half1"  required /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td> Prenom : </td> <td><input name="prenom" type="text" class="input-textarea half1"  required /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><input name="Total" type="submit" value="Suivant" onclick="show('link2')" /></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
        </div>
        <div class="div" id="content2">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td> Adresse Complete :  </td> <td><input name="adresCp" type="text" class="input-textarea half1"  required /> </td>
                </tr>
                        <tr>
                         <td><input name="Total" type="submit" value="Suivant" onclick="show('link3')" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </div>
        <div class="div" id="content3">
                <table>     
                    <tr>
                    <td> Telephone(mobile) : </td> <td><input name="telM" type="text" class="input-textarea half1"  required /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> Telephone(fixe) : </td> <td><input name="telF" type="text" class="input-textarea half1"  required /> </td>
                    </tr>   

                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:315px;"> E-mail :  </td> <td><input name="email"  class="input-textarea half1" type="text"  required /> </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                         <td><input name="Total" type="submit" value="Suivant" onclick="show('link4')" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        <div class="div" id="content4">
                <table>         
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:315px;"> Les photos peuvent donner vie à votre logement  </td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:315px;"> Ajouter une photo :  </td> <td><input type="file" class="input-textarea half1" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                         <td><input name="Total" type="submit" value="Suivant" onclick="show('link5')"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        <div class="div" id="content5s">
                <table>     
                    <tr>
                    <td> Type de travaux  :</td> <td><select name="type_trv">
                                                                 <option selected="selected" hidden >-- Type Travaux --</option>
                                                                 <option value="Jardinage">Jardinage</option>
                                                                 <option value="bricolage">bricolage</option>
                                                                 <option value="Gardiennage">Gardiennage</option>
                                                                 <option value="Sécurite_prive">Sécurité privé</option>
                                                    </select> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Superficie du domicile  : </td> <td><input name="supdomc" type="text" class="input-textarea half"  required /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> nombre d’étages  : </td> <td><input name="nbtag" type="number" min="1" max="10" class="input-textarea half" required /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> nombre chambre  : </td> <td><input name="nbchmbr" type="number" min="1" max="10" class="input-textarea half" required /> </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>jours souhaité des travaux  :</td> <td><input name="jrtv" type="text" class="input-textarea half" required ></number> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fréquence des travaux :  </td> <td>  <input name="frqte" type="text" class="input-textarea half" required /></td> 
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>demande spécifique :</td> <td><textarea name="dmdSpe" cols="50" rows="5" class="input-textarea half"></textarea> </td>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" > <input name="Submit" type="Submit" value="Terminer les etapes "> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
<div id="footer" style="width:315px; height:100px; background-color: red; ">  </div>
</body>
```

js

```
<script>
  function myfun() {
    document.getElementById("ent2").innerHTML = "information de base";
    document.getElementById("content1").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("content2").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("content3").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("content4").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("content5s").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("content2").style.height = '0px';
    document.getElementById("content3").style.height = '0px';
    document.getElementById("content4").style.height = '0px';
    document.getElementById("content5s").style.height = '0px';
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function show(id) {
    document.getElementById("ent2").style.position = "relative";
    if (id == 'link1') {
      document.getElementById("ent2").innerHTML = "information de base";
      var content1 = document.getElementById("content1");
      document.getElementById("content1").style.visibility = 'visible';
      document.getElementById("nav-item1").style.backgroundColor = '#EDEFE0';
      document.getElementById("titre1").style.fontWeight = 'bolder';
      document.getElementById("titre2").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      document.getElementById("titre3").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      document.getElementById("titre4").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      document.getElementById("titre5").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      document.getElementById("nav-item2").style.backgroundColor = '#edefed';
      document.getElementById("nav-item3").style.backgroundColor = '#edefed';
      document.getElementById("nav-item4").style.backgroundColor = '#edefed';
      document.getElementById("nav-item5").style.backgroundColor = '#edefed';
      document.getElementById("content2").style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById("content3").style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById("content4").style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById("content5s").style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = content1.innerHTML;
    } else if (id == 'link2') {
      document.getElementById("ent2").innerHTML = "Adresse";
      var content2 = document.getElementById("content2");
      document.getElementById("content1").style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById("content2").style.visibility = 'visible';
      document.getElementById("nav-item1").style.backgroundColor = '#edefed';
      document.getElementById("nav-item2").style.backgroundColor = '#EDEFE0';
      document.getElementById("titre1").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      document.getElementById("titre2").style.fontWeight = 'bolder';
      document.getElementById("titre3").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      document.getElementById("titre4").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      document.getElementById("titre5").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      document.getElementById("nav-item3").style.backgroundColor = '#edefed';
      document.getElementById("nav-item4").style.backgroundColor = '#edefed';
      document.getElementById("nav-item5").style.backgroundColor = '#edefed';
      document.getElementById("content2").style.position = "absolute";
      document.getElementById("content2").style.top = "40%";
      document.getElementById("content3").style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById("content4").style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById("content5s").style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = content2.innerHTML;
    } else if (id == 'link3') {
      document.getElementById("ent2").innerHTML = "Contact";
      var content3 = document.getElementById("content3");
      document.getElementById("content1").style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById("content2").style.visibility = 'hidden';

      document.getElementById("content3").style.visibility = "visible";
      document.getElementById("nav-item1").style.backgroundColor = '#edefed';
      document.getElementById("nav-item2").style.backgroundColor = '#edefed';
      document.getElementById("nav-item3").style.backgroundColor = '#EDEFE0';
      document.getElementById("titre1").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      document.getElementById("titre2").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      document.getElementById("titre3").style.fontWeight = 'bolder';
      document.getElementById("titre4").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      document.getElementById("titre5").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      document.getElementById("nav-item4").style.backgroundColor = '#edefed';
      document.getElementById("nav-item5").style.backgroundColor = '#edefed';
      document.getElementById("content3").style.position = "absolute";
      document.getElementById("content3").style.top = "40%";

      document.getElementById("content4").style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById("content5s").style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = content3.innerHTML;
    } else if (id == 'link4') {
      document.getElementById("ent2").innerHTML = "Photos";
      var content4 = document.getElementById("content4");
      document.getElementById("content1").style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById("content2").style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById("content3").style.visibility = 'hidden';

      document.getElementById("content4").style.visibility = 'visible';
      document.getElementById("nav-item1").style.backgroundColor = '#edefed';
      document.getElementById("nav-item2").style.backgroundColor = '#edefed';
      document.getElementById("nav-item3").style.backgroundColor = '#edefed';
      document.getElementById("nav-item4").style.backgroundColor = '#EDEFE0';
      document.getElementById("titre1").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      document.getElementById("titre2").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      document.getElementById("titre3").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      document.getElementById("titre4").style.fontWeight = 'bolder';
      document.getElementById("titre5").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      document.getElementById("nav-item5").style.backgroundColor = '#edefed';
      document.getElementById("content4").style.position = "absolute";
      document.getElementById("content4").style.top = "40%";

      document.getElementById("content5s").style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = content4.innerHTML;
    } else if (id == 'link5') {
      /*document.getElementById("content5s").style.height='auto';
      var calc = document.getElementById('content5s').offsetHeight;
      alert(calc);*/

      document.getElementById("ent2").innerHTML = "Plus d'info";
      var content4 = document.getElementById("content5s");
      document.getElementById("content1").style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById("content2").style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById("content3").style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById("content4").style.visibility = 'hidden';

      document.getElementById("content5s").style.visibility = 'visible';
      document.getElementById("nav-item4").style.backgroundColor = '#edefed';
      document.getElementById("nav-item5").style.backgroundColor = '#EDEFE0';
      document.getElementById("titre1").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      document.getElementById("titre2").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      document.getElementById("titre3").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      document.getElementById("titre4").style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      document.getElementById("titre5").style.fontWeight = 'bolder';
      document.getElementById("content5s").style.position = "absolute";
      document.getElementById("content5s").style.top = "40%";
      document.getElementById("content5s").style.height = '20%';
      var calc = document.getElementById('content5s').offsetHeight;
      alert(calc);
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = content4.innerHTML;
    }
  }

  function init() {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      if (divs[i].className == "div") {
        divs[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
    }
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    a.onclick = show;
  }
  window.onload = init;
</script>
```

Comment: please add the minimum amount of code to recreate your issue within your question please.

Comment: @Aaron it's so large plz download it and show it

Answer (score 1):

Use 'display: none' css for hiding division instead of visibility: hidden.

display: absolute will take div control out of flow.

I recommend removing 'display: absolute; height:0px; top: 40%;' and adding 'display: block' for displaying element.

Comment: thanx it works with me thanx an other time @Penchalaiah